# Difference between a TCP Socket and a Connected UDP Socket

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

Default UDP socket plus the Connect() call is a Connected UDP Socket. I know the differences related to TCP and UDP but here I want to know the Difference in just the **sockets**

Comment: You mean besides the reliability of TCP?

Comment: Yes , besides the Connection Orientation Difference between the two

Comment: Are any of the given answers any good, @arjun gulyani ?

Comment: @sanepete The answers do explain much about the difference between TCP and UDP as protocols but didn't find something on the just the sockets.

Answer (score 21):

When using a TCP socket, the tcp stack takes care of the data being sent to the network and being delivered to the receiver, retransmitting it until acknowledged by the receiver. TCP also takes care of flow control, i.e. transmitting the data at a suitable rate for the network connection and receiver. Last, TCP ensures that the receiver gets the data exactly once and in the correct order.

With UDP, the programmer manages the transmission to network directly, and has to take care of lost and out-of order packets as well as flow control and fragmenting data to packets that can be transmitted over the network connection.

Last, as udp and tcp are different protocols, they require different settings in firewalls to allow passing through to the server if the server is behind a firewall. Also you can't send data from a connected (or non-connected) UDP socket to a TCP socket or vice versa.

Conneting the UDP socket just means that send() and recv() can be used to send data to and from the connected address, but it is still UDP data being sent and received so all of the above differences apply. Calling connect() on a UDP socket is something you would do if you do only point-to-point communications using the socket.

Comment: Thanks for the info but i was specifically interested in the difference between the TCP Socket and a Connected UDP Socket for a Client server model

Comment: I tried to add more explanation on connected UDP sockets.

Comment: A good link is this - http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs60/socketprogramming.html

Comment: The above link is good, but not much related to this topic. Be aware.

Comment: @FaceBro why do you say the above link is not related to the topic? In which point do you think the Berkeley sockets  lib is not following UDP and TCP protocol specifications?

Comment: @Maf The poster asked about the difference between TCP and UDP, but the link was about general socket programming APIs.

Comment: @FaceBro in the link you have general socket programming APIs with also an emphasis on the difference between TCP and UDP programming.

Comment: @Maf then that's not helpful, the poster does not need a full book on this(I am sure he can find one easily by himself), it's not accurate .

Comment: I understand your point @FaceBro. You're right.

Answer (score 12):

As it is widely known, transport protocols as TCP and UDP multiplex a single IP address at the source of the transmission and demultiplex another IP address at the destination. That is why port numbers came along. The way in which both protocols multiplex/demultiplex an IP address is what makes their sockets different.

In order to transmit some data with TCP, you simply drop a datagram in the socket and it will flow through a previously created connection. In turn, UDP is connectionless. The existence or absence of a connection requires that the *identifier format* of each socket be different: whereas a TCP socket is identified by the quadruple {source IP address, source port number, destination IP address, destination port number}, an UDP socket is identified by the tuple {destination IP address, destination port number}.

By the above, when a TCP service receives some datagram, it needs to know who sent it (“who” is an IP address + a port number) in order to properly forward it to the application. So, when two TCP datagrams with different source IPs arrive to a host, they will necessarily be delivered to two different sockets (even if the destination is the same). If there were no distinct sockets, there would be no connection handling at all (i.e., TCP would be connectionless).

With an UDP socket, the rule is different: if two arriving UDP datagrams have the same destination IP address and port number, they will be forwarded to the *same* socket, regardless their source IP addresses and/or source port numbers (they may be equal or not). Why bother with different sockets if the transmission is connectionless?

Remember, independently of their respective socket identifier formats,  both TCP and UDP datagrams identify the port number of the sender; i.e., even a connectionless protocol as UDP has to identify the sender of the transmission as Kurose and Ross explain in their pretty good book “Computer Networking - a Top Down Approach”:

> You may be wondering now, what is the purpose of the source port number? ... in the A-to-B segment the source port number serves as part of a “return address” — when B wants to send a segment back to A, the destination port in the B-to-A segment will take its value from the source port value of the A-to-B segment (the complete return address is A’s IP address and the source port number).

A final remark on nomenclature: here I used the term “datagram” generically, denoting the Protocol Data Unit (PDU) of both TCP and UDP protocols. Kurose and Ross use “segment” with the same intent. However, rigourosly speaking, “segment” is the PDU of the TCP protocol whereas “datagram” is the PDU of the UDP.

Comment: many things of what you wrote make no sense. Finding the path has nothing to do with either TCP or UDP.  Both TCP  AND Udp include information regarding the source of data packets. Then I stopped reading. This should be deleted.

Comment: @Rafal Honestly, I am not sure if I am following you. First, I didn't state that "finding the path" has something to do "with either TCP or UDP" as you said. Also, to quote Kurose and Ross, "it is important to note that a UDP socket is fully identified by a two-tuple consisting of a destination IP address and a destination port number", which was exactly what I stated. I can detect no mistakes in my answer - aren't we facing a language issue here as English is not my first language? Would you mind to clarify what are your concerns here?

Comment: The only language "typo" in this great answer is in `"a connectionless protocol as UDP have to identify"`. Just replace `"have"` with `"has"`. Thanks a lot for your answer @HumbertoFioravanteFerro. The technical details are very fine and you just quoted my second best computer network book after the "bottom up" approach by Tanenbaum et al.

@Vega4 could you please explain the reason why you wrote a so rude comment to this answer without any technical justification?